# PHP Eval String - Alternative?

Tags: php, eval

In a text file (eg. file1.txt), let's say I have a line of php:

```
myArray['index'] = "awesome"
```

In my PHP file (eg. file2.php) I have this line of text imported and assigned to $string.

Is there a way to evaluate the contents of $string without using the eval function?

I currently do:

```
eval("{$string};");
```

To clarify the reason I am asking:
I've read that using eval is "evil". For this reason I want to see if there is an alternative method of evaluating php code that is stored in a text file. I know it might seem weird. You may be thinking "why don't you just write the code in the php file?", but the reason I'm doing this is not really my question. I'm just wondering about alternatives to using eval. Thanks.

Comment: What is the "line of php" doing in a text file? Is this the only such line/construct?

Comment: No. It's actually in an XML file ... but that's not really important for the question. I've clarified what I'm trying to ask above.

Comment: Well, it's not actually the eval function that is evil, its executing text as code that is evil, no matter which way you do it. The reason is that executing text as code opens up so many unknown security risks.

Answer (score 1):

Put a <?php in the top of the file and then include() it. But if any of the file's contents come from untrusted users, you have a security vulnerability on your hands.

Comment: I think I was unclear with the question. I've clarified it above.